# Oracle APEX: Setting "Display Image" page item through PL SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table `IMAGE_TABLE` with two columns `ID - NUMBER` and `IMAGE - BLOB`. I have an APEX page with page item `P1_ID` as hidden and `P1_IMAGE` with type as `"Diaplay Image"` and "Based On" as "BLOB Column returned by SQL Statement".

SQL is as follows: `SELECT IMAGE FROM IMAGE_TABLE WHERE ID = :P1_ID;`

On page load, I set P1_ID as 1.

I have two buttons, "Previous" & "Next". When Next button is pressed, I want to get the next image with a dynamic action with true action as "Execute PL/SQL Code" and code as follows.

```
:P1_ID := :P1_ID + 1; ( :P1_ID := :P1_ID - 1; for PREV button )
SELECT IMAGE INTO :P1_IMAGE FROM IMAGE_TABLE WHERE ID = :P1_ID;
```

Items to Submit: `:P1_ID`

Items to Return: `:P1_ID, :P1_IMAGE`

When I save this PL/SQL Code, I am getting an error `"ORA-06550: line 23, column 8: PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB"`.

The idea is that I don't want to submit the page again with the next or prev button clicks but do a region refresh (as the second true action to this dynamic action) to load the new image.

Any clue on what my mistake is and how to achieve this ?

My APEX version is "18.1" and Oracle version is "11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is

1. refresh the region with a dynamic action
2. ensure the new P1_ID
   is set in 'page items to submit' for the region displaying the
   image

You shouldn't need a P1_IMAGE page item to store the image blob - that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the reply. I removed problematic SQL statement from dynamic action. I tried both item refresh and region refresh. Unfortunately, my image is not getting refreshed. Old image stays. From session variables, I see that P1_ID is getting incremented. Any further suggessions.

Comment: So numerous clicks do not change the image, while session state continues to change? Is other data on the report changing? Perhaps build an example on apex.oracle.com

Comment: Tried creating my application in apex.oracle.com. When I try to upload a file, I get the error "Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for" at the sql staement "select blob_content into var_blob from APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES where name = :P1_FILE_BROWSE;". Its my first application in this environment. Can you please help correcting this as the first step. Thank you. WorkSpace: Sri, User: guest, Pass: a1b2c3d4

Comment: File upload is designed to be processed on submit. I've modified to make the process work.

Comment: And the sample provided appears to be more about uploading the file, than iterating through records?

Comment: Thanks @Scott, for your time. I noticed that my "Save BLOB" is moved from dynamic action to "Processes". I am able to save couple of images there. Now, I can show you what my problem is. I set P1_ID to 1 if its empty. Then two buttons "Back" and "Next". They both have a PL SQL Dynamic action attached to them to add / subtract 1 from P1_ID. Then another dynamic action to refresh the region. When I run this page, I see that P1_ID is getting the new value (ID) but image still remains the old one. I would request you to help me on how to refresh the image, without page submit. Thank you.